# Does $this->Html->url() generate RESTful URL?

Tags: web-services, rest, cakephp

I use CakePHP 2.4.6.

In routes.php, I put

```
Router::mapResources('themes');
```

Then, I can access 'localhost/themes/211' which display screen generated by the action "view" of the controller "themes" just as I expect.

BUt in a view file, I use

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'themes',
    'action' => 'view',
    $theme['Theme']['id']));
?>
```

Then this generate '/themes/view/211' in html, where I expected '/themes/211'.

Does $this->Html->url() generate RESTful URL?

If not, How can Cake view file generate RESTful URL in other way?

Do I do any mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

leave the action blank

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'themes',
    'action' => '',
    $theme['Theme']['id']));
?>
```

Or,

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'themes',
    'action' =>$theme['Theme']['id']
    ));
?>
```

Comment: But in either way, In case i choose back not to use REST, I have to modify back the view file as well.
Because in that case, the url generated by your way is not connected any action/controller.
If possible, I prefer the way useful in both case,using REST and not using REST.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to happen, go to your \app\Config\routes.php and add `Router::connect('/themes', array('controller' => 'themes', 'action' => 'view'));`

You don't have to change

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'themes',
    'action' => 'view',
    $theme['Theme']['id']));
?>
```

Comment: I understand that putting "Router::mapResources('themes');" in routes.php doesn't mean automatically enable Html->url() to generate RESTful url.

Comment: yeah you are right, you need to be specific, because normally /themes refers to /themes/index not themes/view so you need to specifically specify what you want in routes.php

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some more Restfull api calls to define, so maybe something more generic:

```
Router::connect('/api/:controller', array('api' => true, 'action' => 'index', "[method]" => "GET"), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '([0-9]+|me)'));
Router::connect('/api/:controller', array('api' => true, 'action' => 'add', "[method]" => "POST"), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '([0-9]+|me)'));
Router::connect('/api/:controller/:id', array('api' => true, 'action' => 'view', "[method]" => "GET"), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '([0-9]+|me)'));
Router::connect('/api/:controller/:id', array('api' => true, 'action' => 'edit', "[method]" => "POST"), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '([0-9]+|me)'));
```

These route calls like "api/Themes/123" to the action index in the Themes controller, however, if you try and do a POST request it will route to the add action.

Comment: Thanks,Joris!
I understand that putting "Router::mapResources('themes');" in routes.php doesn't mean automatically enable Html->url() to generate RESTful url.

In case I need to make api, I will use

Comment: In case I need to make api, I will use your solution.
But in my case I don't have to make api.
The reason why I want use RESTful url is that I think using RESTful url and using fixed lilmited actions in web application means better developing when I read Rails manual.